# Create new Cloud Tasks queue on demand

Tags: queue, cloud, gcloud

I'm looking into Cloud Tasks as the backbone for an app I am building. The way I envision my app is that for each individual customer, a new queue will be created. This will allow me to take advantage of the inbuilt rate limit features of Google Tasks, which operate on a per-queue basis. This will mean I can easily adjust rates on a per-customer basis.

Unfortunately all I can find in the documentation is the ability to create a queue manually, using the [GCloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/quickstart-appengine#create_a_cloud_tasks_queue)

Does anyone know a way that I can create a queue programatically, in response to a new customer signing up? Bonus if it's doable through Cloud Functions.

Alternatively is there better products out there that will let me spin up lots of queues simultaneously?

Comment: See: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/libraries Do you have a language preference? Also you can always append `--log-http` to `gcloud` commands to determine the underling calls. Then use APIs Explorer to model what you want to do

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2beta3/projects.locations.queues/create

Comment: Keep in mind [Cloud Tasks quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/quotas). After user signup you can [send](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#publishing_messages) message to pubsub which [triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#publishing_a_message_from_within_a_function) Cloud Function and it creates a task queue using a library.